# URLConnection.getInputStream returns null

Tags: java, urlconnection

I use Java 6 to send XML data to a server.

The Method writeToURL from the XMLWriter class uses a URLConnection for sending the XML data to my web service. The XML is successfully transferred and stored in the database, but instead of receiving the below-mentioned response I get only null. There is also no exception thrown.

As result there should be the following XML or an InputStream containing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    <type>response</type>
    <messageID>k17436fxOD3y1ywhCX48</messageID>
    <status>successful</status>
</message>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    <type>response</type>
    <messageID>k17436fxOD3y1ywhCX48</messageID>
    <status>alreadyExisting</status>
</message>
```

The complete Code of the XML class can be found [here](http://paste.geekosphere.org/qxwb).
The webservice runs on this url: `http://wafriv.de/tatoo_webservice/index.php`
A XML sample to send to the webservice could be found on http://paste.geekosphere.org/p5bf

Any help would be appreciated.

[edit]
The code I have problems with is the method writeToURL from my XMLWriter.
Here it is:

```
try
{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    String query = "";

    if (additionalParams != null)
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : additionalParams.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            query += String.format("%s=%s&", URLEncoder.encode(key, charset), URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), charset));
        }
    }

    TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(this.document);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    query += String.format("%s=%s", URLEncoder.encode("message", charset), URLEncoder.encode(sw.toString(), charset));

    OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
    InputStream response;
    try
    {
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), charset);
        writer.write(query); // Write POST query string (if any needed).
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                this.exceptionList.add(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    response = connection.getInputStream();

    return response;
}
catch (TransformerConfigurationException ex)
{
    this.exceptionList.add(ex);
}
catch (TransformerException ex)
{
    this.exceptionList.add(ex);
}
catch (MalformedURLException ex)
{
    this.exceptionList.add(ex);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    this.exceptionList.add(ex);
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.exceptionList.add(ex);
}
finally
{
    this.printExceptions();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please show the java code you have problems with.

Comment: I've added the code. It could also be found on http://paste.geekosphere.org/qxwb as I already mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is solved. The finally cause the method writeToURL to return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The `finally` caused the method writeToURL to return null.